# Syntax error on last letter of class name

Tags: java, syntax, compilation, sublimetext

I'm currently starting to learn java in a course at uni and have a problem with the most basic code in Sublime. When trying to compile I get this error:

```
>>> javac HelloWorld.java
  File "<string>", line 1
    javac HelloWorld.java
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The file name is obviously "HelloWorld.java" and to compile I put "javac HelloWorld.java" in to the console. When I tried compiling this with the Terminal on my mac it worked fine and created a .class.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println ("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: You say "on my mac"; what kind of system does this fail to compile on?

Comment: It is Mac OS X El Capitan and the program im using is SublimeText if thats what you are asking for ? Sorry I really am new to all of this.

Comment: Is that the whole content of HelloWorld.java? No package declaration etc.?

Comment: Yes this is all the content @assylias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that the Sublime console (opened via <kbd>Ctrl+`</kbd> or `View > Show Console` from the menu) is **not a terminal**. It's a Python console for interacting with the Python interpreter built into Sublime.

In order to compile your code you should make sure that the Build System (`Tools > Build System` in the menu) is set to either `Automatic`, `JavaC` or `Ant` (but you need to have an `Ant` build file available to use that build system).

Once you've done that, you can select `Tools > Build` from the menu in order to compile your code. There is a key binding for this that you will see next to the associated menu item.

Note that this will only compile your code to a class file, it won't run it. You can see my answer in [this forum post](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/java-build-system-not-working/25745) for more information on how this can be set up to compile and run your program in one step (and also caveats on why with Java it's generally not a good idea in the long run).

In short, you can create a file with the following contents, store it in your `User` package (`Sublime Text > Preferences > Browse Packages...` will tell you where that is) as `MyJavaBuild.sublime-build`, and then select `MyJavaBuild` from the build system menu I referenced above in order to build and compile in one step.

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "javac $file_name && java $file_base_name",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```